# SIGSEGV error(runtime error)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

[This](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/2-fast-2-furious/description/) is the problem I'm trying to solve.

This is my attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
long long   int n;
cin>>n;
long    long int a[n],b[n],i,max1=0,max2=0;
a[0]=0;
for(i=1;i<n+1;i++){
cin>>a[i];
if(abs(a[i]-a[i-1])>max1) 
max1=abs(a[i]-a[i-1]);

}
b[0]=0;
for(i=1;i<n+1;i++){
cin>>b[i];
if(abs(b[i]-b[i-1])>max2)
max2=abs(b[i]-b[i-1]);
}

if(max1>max2)
{   cout<<"Dom"<<endl;
cout<<max1;}
else    if(max1<max2)
{   cout<<"Brian"<<endl;
cout<<max2; }
else
{
cout<<"Tie"<<endl;
cout<<max1;
}
//cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

On execution, it segfaults, though.

Can anybody help me resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The loop will always write one element beyond the array boundaries, since the maximum value of `i` is `n` in the loop. Either allocate `n + 1` memory for the arrays each or set the looping condition to `i < n`.